# Suppress Adobe window while printing

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to print a PDF document from VB.NET program. The following code works but the Adobe  blank screen comes up while printing. Is there a way to suppress this window?

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
startInfo.FileName = "Test.pdf"
startInfo.Verb = "print"
startInfo.Arguments = ""
startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
Dim report As Process = New Process
report.StartInfo = startInfo
report.Start()
```

Comment: Have you tried setting CreateNoWindow to true?

Comment: Set CreateNoWindow to true but the window still appears

Comment: CreateNoWindow can only work on console apps.  Your only hope is WindowStyle = Hidden.  Low odds, Adobe products were designed to be annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that you aren't actually invoking Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader here, you are asking the shell to do something for you, and the shell is going to do whatever the registry says to do, and the registry is going to do whatever the installer for the program setup in the first place.

When you set the `ProcessStartInfo`'s `FileName` property you'll be able to examine the `Verbs` property and see available verbs for that file extension. You can see the list of verbs for `.pdf` by looking in the registry under `HKCL\.pdf` and taking note of the "(Default)" value, in my case `AcroExch.Document`. Then navigate to whatever that is under `HKCL`, in my case its `HKCL\AcroExch.Document` and look in the `shell` subkey. For each of the verbs there's a command to run and that's program dependent. Mine is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /p /h "%1"
```

So when I "execute" a PDF as you are using the "print" verb, my PDF is passed to the `%1` parameter above. Even if I supplied additional arguments they would not get passed because this key is only looking for one.

Older versions of Acrobat supported "silent printing" but according to [this post](http://acrobatusers.com/forum/printing-prepress/command-line-parameters-silent-printing-acrobat-professional) they were removed around version 8 for security reasons. I'm guessing basically that Adobe wanted people to know whenever their program was invoked.

Also, because you are asking the shell to do something for you, `CreateNoWindow` is relative to the shell but not what the shell is doing, so that won't work for you either.

If you really want to print without a UI then you'll need to look at actually using COM or something else to talk directly to Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader, or another program such as Ghostscript.